# Unable to connect the Entity Data Model to a SQL Server database file

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity, version, data-files

I created a `.mdf` database file using VS 2017 on a developer workstation. I then copied it across to a different workstation and then tried to use VS2017 to connect to the `.mdf` data file again and generate an Entity Data Model.

I get the error

> Database.mdf cannot be opened because it is version 869. This server supports version 852.

Both workstations have SQL Server 2017 on them as well as SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2012. In both cases I can connect with SQL Server 2017 to the `.mdf` file.

The error message talks about a server yet I'm not hosting the `.MDF` file on a server. It is a stand alone file.

Does VS2017 connect with SQL Server Express or EF libraries. What is it that I need to upgrade so that VS 2017 can connect to this `.mdf` file ?

Erick

Comment: Version **869** internally is SQL Server 2017 - so you've created the file with a SQL Server 2017 version. However, **852** is SQL Server 2016, so it seems on your second PC, you're running / using SQL Server 2016 - and you just **simply CANNOT** attach/open/restore/use a SQL Server database (file) from a newer version of SQL Server in an older one - just won't work. So you need to find a way to use SQL Server **2017** on your second PC to open/use this file

Comment: And btw: SQL Server - as the name already implies - is **always** a server component - even if you use a "standalone" `.mdf` file - to use it, there must be a  SQL **Server** instance running somewhere .....

Comment: I do not see sql server 2016 on my workstation.  Could the SQLExpress be SQL2016 ?  the Dev machine has SQL Server 2008, 2012 and 2017.  But we have never run 2016 here.

Comment: Find out which **instance** of SQL Server is used to run in your application - and yes, of course, SQL Server Express or SQL Server LocalDB could be a 2016 version....

Comment: using SQL database without a sql server https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/use-of-data-base-without-installing-sql-server-using-visual/   I believe it uses SQLExpress.  That must be what VS is trying to use to connect to the mdf file.  I'm unable to find what version of SQL express is on the workstation through installed apps.  However, a SQL Express for 2017 does exist.  I'll see if can download it and work with that.